# How do you set the startup project in CodeLite?

Tags: c++, codelite

My codelite workspace has two projects, one is an **executable** and the other is a **static library**. The executable links with the static library and building everything is fine. However, whenever I click the run button, codelite tries to run the library which **obviously** results in an error. Is there a way to tell codelite to **run the executable instead of the library**?

Answer (score 2):

In order to set the startup project, you must **right-click** on the project then select **Make Active** from the drop-down menu, or simply double-click the project.